# Start Apache2 and Tomcat on Startup on Ubuntu

Tags: server, bash, apache2, tomcat

Apologies if this has been answered elsewhere, I know little about either of these services.

At work, we have a server that is normally on all the time, but when the power goes out, it shuts off. Our IT guy is currently WFH, and since I'm the only other person here with any kind of Linux experience, I have the privilege of getting it back up and running.

He gave me the credentials to go in and start everything back up, but I know there is a better way to do it, I just cannot seem to figure it out. Right now, I go in as su, and then do `service apache2 start` and then `service tomcat start`. How can I build a bash script that doesn't need su privileges that will run at startup?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could search/ask at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I don't think I knew Server Fault existed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you have built tomcat, but if it was built as a service then you can use `systemctl`

to enable apache2 and tomcat at startup

```bash
sudo systemctl enable apache2
sudo systemctl enable tomact
```

Comment: I'll have to ask how it was built, though I doubt the person who did it will remember. Thanks for the information though, it'll help my research